# WPF Datagrid how to get the Fontsize of a header?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to get the FontSize, etc. of a DatagridColumn Header- unfortunately, I have no idea how to get this in C#.

My code looks like:

```
  public void AutoGeneratedColumns(DataGrid dgrid)
        {
   foreach (DataGridColumn col in dgrid.Columns)
            {
                var headerText = col.Header.ToString();
                Style headerStyle = col.Header
                double FontSize = Style.????
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in the `HeaderStyle` property?

Comment: Jup, a bunch of setters, but only ones I set explicitly, not the implicit ones like FontSize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a review of default style using blend or (if you still can find it) look at the WPF default themes.  This should give you a big clue on what bits are inheriting from what and how the headers are constructed.  You should be then able to develop some code to programmatically dig through the logical tree to get you values you need at runtime.

Comment: Ahh it's the datagrid, which gives access to the header cell. this is the solution, thank you :)